# Obtaining the "Receivers Companion" for Apache Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Does anyone know where I can get a compiled distribution of the Receivers Companion for Log4j?

The Apache [project information](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/index.html) for it is cryptically short.

I've found the SVN repository, but I've had some trouble getting it to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j is no longer being actively developed. Have you considered [logback](http://logback.qos.ch), log4j successor? It has many additional features you might find useful.

Disclosure: I am the founder of both log4j and logback projects.